# forward proxy with apache

Tags: apache, proxy

I need to setup apache to be able to do following (if possible):

When i requesting http://localhost/ i need to get content from http://google.com
Main thing is i don't need to be redirected, but i need that on localhost domain request i can get content that was actually taken from google.com and browser still stay at localhost domain (i think apache can do that behind the scene)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)

```
ProxyPass / "http://www.google.com/"
```

Comment: I tryed ProxyPass and it just redirecting me to remote address

Comment: Yes correct. Problem was not in apache setup, just remote host redirect all requests from http to https that's why i get redirect too

Comment: ProxyPassReverse will rewrite Location headers and may work for what you're doing.  But remember, if the remote site is forcing a redirect to https, there is probably a good reason.